# Error Loading RSS XML: Element 'channel' with namespace name '' was not found.

Tags: c#, .net, rss

I have an exception here

```
var stream = e.Result;
var response = XmlReader.Create(stream);
var feeds = SyndicationFeed.Load(response); // IT IS HERE
```

**The exception**

> Element 'channel' with namespace name '' was not found. Line 8,
>   position 2.

RSS looks like:

```
 <rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
 <atom:link href="http://dallas.example.com/rss.xml" rel="self"
 type="application/rss+xml" /> <channel> <title>News</title>
 <link>http://www.samsung.com/us</link> <description>News</description>
 ...
```

http://validator.w3.org/feed/ says that "This is a valid RSS feed." (You can check it here http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.samsung.com%2Fus%2Ffunction%2Frss%2FrssFeedItemList.do%3FctgryCd%3D101%26typeCd%3DNEWS)

So I have no clue whats happening... :(

Can we workaround to suppress some of the validation message of the [SyndicationFeed class](https://www.google.com.uy/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx&ei=YLVkUd-pBobc9QTYvoGgAQ&usg=AFQjCNEKu8-GnZML3UVFSn_bt63Uuc-dEQ&sig2=ADXanIyC3xu_EB74GrT-_g&bvm=bv.44990110,d.eWU)?

Thank you for ANY solution that will give me the chance forget about this exception!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the results from the W3 validation you listed, it reads:

```
line 8, column 0: Undocumented use of atom:link
```

The `atom:link` element being placed before the `channel` element is causing the `SyndicationFeed` class to fail on load. You can test this yourself by downloading the rss feed xml locally, removing/commenting the `atom:link` line and running your code again. Without that line, the xml loads and the feeds are found. This has [happened before](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/1ecd41a0-83a3-4ac7-9abc-5ff08b52b890/) with the `SyndicationFeed` class.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know about what specification says about `atom:link` ? Should it be there?

Comment: Even though the W3 validation considers the feed 'valid', the `SyndicationFeed.Load()` method is a bit more brittle and expects the `atom:link` tag to be elsewhere, like as a child element of the `channel` element. You can check out the [Atom](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4287) and [RSS](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html) specs for more details on element placement.

Comment: Also...Check the `atom:link` [Recommendations](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-profile#namespace-elements-atom-link) section of the RSS Advisory Board, and you'll see that an acceptable placement is within `channel`.

Comment: Cool. Also I found this http://feedvalidator.org/docs/warning/MissingAtomSelfLink.html and it says: Then insert a `atom:link` to your feed in the channel section. Below is an example to get you started. Be sure to replace the value of the href attribute with the URL of your feed.

<atom:link href="http://dallas.example.com/rss.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Michael’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15915882), I was able to pre-process the offending XML (which is not under my control) to move errant `atom:link` elements:

```cs
private static readonly XName AtomLink = XName.Get( "link", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" );
private static readonly XName Channel = XName.Get( "channel" );

...
var document = XDocument.Load( stream );
var channel = document.Root.Element( Channel );
foreach( var misplacedLink in document.Root.Elements( AtomLink ) ) {
    misplacedLink.Remove( );
    channel.Add( misplacedLink );
}

using( var reader = document.CreateReader( ) )
    return SyndicationFeed.Load( reader );
```